# SwiftUI: Navigate from a view with a navigationbackbutton to a fullscreen view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I am making a menu for my game using `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink`. I have three views as such:

```
struct MainMenuView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            // relevant stuff
            NavigationLink(destination: CustomGameSettingsView()) {
                Text("Custom Game")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct CustomGameSettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            // ui to change game settings and stuff
            NavigationLink(destination: MyGameView(customSettings)) {
                Text("Play Game!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `CustomGameSettingsView` shows the `navigationBarBackButton`

```
struct MyGameView: View {
    var body: some View {
        myGameViews {
            // stuff
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("myGame"))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])

        // these are the things I have tried to get rid of the navigationBackButton
    }
    .onAppear() {
        self.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    } // another thing I tried
}
```

When I navigate from `MainMenuView` to `CustomGameSettingsView`, I gain a `navigationBarBackButton` which stays with me when I navigate to `MyGameView`. How do I get rid of that on the final navigation? I want the back button on the settings menu but I want my game to be fullscreen. Is `NavigationView` the wrong tool in this instance?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you use another `NavigationView{}` inside the `CustomGameSettingsView`. You don't have to use another **NavigationView** because all your views (except MainMenuView) are already inside the **NavigationView** of the `MainMenuView`.

To fix this, replace the **NavigationView** inside the `CustomGameSettingsView` with a different container, then everything will work fine. Also, remove all your `onAppear{}`.

```
struct CustomGameSettingsView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack { //replace NavigationView with something else
        NavigationLink(destination: MyGameView()) {
            Text("Play Game!")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that the NavigationView would remain after the navigations.